# Detect Consecutive Occurance and populate start&end date

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R and I would like to detect the consecutive periods of Anomaly. Below is an example, is there a way to do this?

Before:

```
> dput(head(table))

structure(list(Anomaly = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No Anomaly", 
"Anomaly"), class = "factor"), Starttime = structure(c(1517385625.68442, 
1517385922.68722, 1517386231.1695, 1517386508.06496, 1517386945.86432, 
1517387727.89725), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    Endtime = structure(c(1517385922.68714, 1517386231.1695, 
    1517386508.06496, 1517386937.51527, 1517387727.89725, 1517388548.49825
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("Anomaly", 
"Starttime", "Endtime"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

After:

Anomaly, Starttime, Endtime

Anomaly 1, 2018-01-31 08:10:31, 2018-01-31 08:22:17

Anomaly 2, 2018-01-31 08:35:27, 2018-01-31 08:49:08

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example data instead of images

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  What @akrun means is to do this in your console: `dput(your_dataframe)` and then copy the output as a codeblock in your answer. If it's large, maybe just use `dput(head(your_dataframe))`.

Comment: There is no 09:40:18 in your example

Comment: Corrected it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping column

```
library(data.table)
```

and then search for

```
?rleid
```

According to the description of `?rleid`

> A convenience function for generating a run-length type id column to
>   be used in grouping operations. It accepts atomic vectors, lists,
>   data.frames or data.tables as input.

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[Anomaly == "Anomaly"], rleid(Anomaly)]
```

The `setDT` converts the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by the `run-length-id` of 'Anomaly', filter the rows of the Subset of Data.table (`Anomaly == "Anomaly"`) and apply the logic

Suppose, if we need to get the first and last 'Starttime', 'Endtime' for each consecutive 'Anomaly'

```
setDT(df1)[, {i1 <- Anomaly == 'Anomaly'
          .(Starttime = Starttime[i1][1], Endtime = Endtime[i1][.N])},
      by = .(grp = rleid(Anomaly))
      ][!is.na(Starttime)][, grp := paste0("Anomaly", seq_len(.N))][]
#         grp           Starttime             Endtime
#1: Anomaly1 2018-01-31 08:10:31 2018-01-31 08:22:17    
#2: Anomaly2 2018-01-31 08:35:27 2018-01-31 08:49:08
```

---

Or another option is using `tidyverse`, by checking the adjacent elements in 'Anomaly' to create the grouping variable and then `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp =  cumsum(Anomaly != lag(Anomaly, default = Anomaly[1]))) %>% 
   filter(Anomaly == "Anomaly") %>% 
   summarise(Starttime = first(Starttime), Endtime = last(Endtime)) %>%
   rename(Anomaly = grp)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Anomaly  Starttime           Endtime            
#   <int>    <dttm>              <dttm>             
#1     1 2018-01-31 08:10:31 2018-01-31 08:22:17
#2     3 2018-01-31 08:35:27 2018-01-31 08:49:08
```